# AWS CloudFormation Rate Exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment

I am running a multi-branch pipeline in Jenkins for CI/CD that deploys a CloudFormation stack to my AWS account. Occasionally, when multiple developers push to their branches at the same time, I receive this error on one or more branches:

> com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.model.AmazonCloudFormationException:
>   Rate exceeded (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error
>   Code: Throttling;

This seems to be a rate limit that Amazon has imposed on the number of requests to CloudFormation within a specified time frame.

What is the request limit of CloudFormation, and can I request a limit increase?

Comment: There seems to be a list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html), it doesn't mention anything about rate limits though

Comment: Just got such issue when started deletion of 14 stacks through AWS UI. It was around ~200 `AWS::SSM::Parameter` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - Not the requests to the cloudformation API.

Most likely the issue will be that Jenkins pipeline requesting for updates every few seconds in order to get the current status.  And when you are deploying multiple stacks you will hit this error.

This is probably a bug in the Cloudformation plugin in Jenkins - you'll need to raise a ticket and ask them to implement a backoff of requests if the cfn stack is taking longer than expected, so that it doesn't keep requesting the status of the stack as often.

You could also change your Jenkinsfile's to use the aws-cli which do a better job of managing requests to AWS on cfn updates.